# Ansible and conditional install of software

Tags: linux, ansible

Ansible is great for rolling out (in our case JBoss). One part of the playbook is:

```
- name: copy jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz to server
  action: copy src=jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz
               dest=/tmp/jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz
               owner=root
               group=root

- name: Extracting jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz
  command: /bin/tar xfz /tmp/jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz -C /opt
```

which works like a charm, except it works every time, and I would like Ansible to stop the playbook when JBoss is already installed (in our case, the test is if `/opt/jboss-eap-6.2.0` does exist. What is the neatest way to do this ? Can you provide a test if something exist on a target server in a when-clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wanted to skip command execution then `creates` parameter of `command` [module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html)  would solve your problem. It instructs the module to skip execution of the command if destination file/directory already exists.

Here's an example:

```
- name: Extracting jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz
  command: creates=/opt/jboss_dir /bin/tar xfz /tmp/jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Your particular case is a bit more tricky. Firstly, your archive may not survive restarts because you're copying to `/tmp`, so it may be copied every time you execute the playbook. Secondly it may be required to introduce an extra task only to check for jboss directory existence.

The following task will:

- create `/opt/jboss_dir` directory if it doesn't exist yet, the result of this task will be stored in `jbossDirectory` variable
- if `jbossDirectory` has `changed` status, the archive will be copied to `/tmp`
- the same `changed` status will also cause extraction of archive

Example playbook:

```
- name: create jboss directory
  file: state=directory dest=/opt/jboss_dir owner=root user=root
  register: jbossDirectory

- name: copy jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz to server
  copy: src=jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz dest=/tmp/jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz owner=root group=root
  when: jbossDirectory|changed

- name: extracti jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz
  command: /bin/tar xfz /tmp/jboss-eap-6.2.0.tar.gz -C /opt
  when: jbossDirectory|changed
```